# Building an android app that will create remote access between phone and pc & be able to share files

Tags: android

I am almost a newbie in android . Now , I want to build an app that will create remote access between my phone & windows pc .  I am looking for some suggestions . 
If you guys can help me by giving some tips about what should I do or what should I learn that will be a great pleasure .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're starting from scratch I would head over to the [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/index.html) and start working through the excellent material they have there.

Also there are some great Google I/O videos up on getting started. [This](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=3RmoWK0KADs) is just one example.

Last but not least a lot of groundwork has already been done on this and there are many apps already doing similar things. That being said, you've got some great projects and example code to review before beginning your endeavour. First up, I'd recommend checking out [Google's VNC Viewer project for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/).

Best of luck!